# Java Swing - mouseMoved event is fired slowly

Tags: java, swing, mouse

Currently I am experiencing issues with the mouseMoved event in Java - Swing. Briefly, I have got a JPanel and I have attached MouseMotionListener to it, in order to hide or show JscrollPane on the fly:

```
myPanel.addMouseMotionListener(new MousePresenter());
```

I have got my own class that implements MouseMotionListener interface:

```
public class MousePresenter implements MouseMotionListener { 

  public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
   int x = e.getX();
   int y = e.getY();

   if (x>20 && x<200) {
    hideScrollBar();
   }
   else {
    showScrollBar();
   }

  }

}
```

The issue is that the mouseMoved event is not being fired often enough. Is there any related solution to this issue whilst using MouseMotionListener?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: _not being fired often enough_ - what exactly is enough vs. not enough? Typically, there is no problem to be expected, so something in your code elsewhere (or maybe expectation: you can't get nanosecond resolution :-) is wrong. Show us an SSCCE (google for the term if you don't know ) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Probably something in my code is wrong, as you have mentioned. There has to be some some sort of "performance bug" in there that causes the delays. Thank you for your effort, I will try to sort it out.

Comment: The problem your facing is probably due to some OS optimisation. Rather the firing every exact position change, it's coalescing the calls to make the calls faster and more efficient so as not to drown the event queues. You can track this by painting points over the screen where the mouse events occur, the faster you move the mouse, the further apart the points

Answer (score 2):

The following seems to work just fine for me. Note that the handling of the event is rather fast:

```
  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame( "TestFrame" );
        JPanel content = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );

        final JLabel mousePosition = new JLabel( "Unknown" );
        content.add( mousePosition, BorderLayout.NORTH );

        content.addMouseMotionListener( new MouseMotionAdapter() {
          @Override
          public void mouseMoved( MouseEvent e ) {
            mousePosition.setText( "X: " + e.getX() + " Y: " + e.getY() );
          }
        } );
        frame.setContentPane( content );
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
      }
    } );
  }
```

That might not be the case for your `hideScrollBar` method

Answer (score 1):

A mouse moved event is inherently slowly since it's fired on every pixel change.

The only thing you can do to optimize the whole issue is to optimize what you do inside the callback handler. In your case you do have

```
if (something)
  doA();
else
  doB();
```

This means that in any case you are either trying to show or to hide the scrollbar even when it's already shown or hidden. What you can do is:

```
if (scrollBarIsVisible && x>20 && x<200) {
  hideScrollBar();
  scrollBarIsVisible = false;
}
else if (!scrollBarIsVisible) {
  showScrollBar();
  scrollBarIsVisible = true;
}
```

So that you only modify the visibility of the element (which can be a heavy operation since it may require to relayout things) when switching from inside the bounds to outside and viceversa. This should lower the computational operations by a lot.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually my code is quite optimized, I have put the example above just for the sake of clarity and I hide the scrollbar only if visible, as in your example :) Still, the issue is that the mouseMoved event is being fired slowly.

Comment: _only thing you can do to optimize_ actually, you don't - and _can't!_ - know what/where/how-to optimize without measuring. This way of assumed micro-improvement at the price of smearing logic and whacky flags into listener code will fire back at you sooner or later. Plus have no measurable effect at all (my assumptions :-)

Comment: _mouse moved event is inherently slowly since it's fired on every pixel change_ that's not slow at all: without a pixel change there trivially wouldn't be a move to notify about ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you all your code is being executed in the Event Dispatch thread it could be causing problems. Have a look at this [trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) and try to put any code that does a lot of work in a [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) thread.

Comment: which part of listening to mouseEvents and changing a JSomething property accordingly would you move into a background thread? (Hint: it's a trick question :-)

Comment: I suspect his application does more than whats listed in the short code snippet above

Comment: Thank you, I dont know the SwingWorker thread and will take a look.

Comment: Anyway, the issue still preserves. If I remove the hideScrollBar() and showScrollBar() calls, the whole mouseMoved method is still being fired slowly.The thing is, that when I attach the MouseMotionListener to a JList, the events are fired incredibly fast :)

Comment: @KarelBurda please specify slowly. The code snippet in my answer behaves just as I expect, and that is not slow at all

Comment: Your code snippet works really fast and my GUI is quite complex, so that might be the case. I will try to put some parts of the whole code into the SwingWorker thread. When I attached MouseMotionListener to my JPanel, it has fired like 3 events per 5 seconds. But when I attached it to my JList, it has fired like 10 events per 1 second.

Comment: @KarelBurda it shouldn't matter whether the UI is complex. But are you certain other components are not handling the events. For example if you take my code snippet and add a button in the center, the listener will not be triggered when moving over the button

Comment: @Karel Burda _whole code into the SwingWorker thread_ be careful: a SwingWorker **does not** help for stuff that must happen on the EDT. In your shoes I would first try to isolate the bottleneck (probably not the event/handling, so it is safe to put _the other_ stuff in a worker thread :-)

Comment: @Robin, good point, but the listeners are attached correctly. I consider this as a performance issue within my code. Thank you.

Comment: @kleopatra Yes, that is basically what I meant :) From what I learned, the SwingWorker is rather intended for the "background stuff". Anyway, I'm going to isolate the bottleneck, since this is quite a hack of performance issue. Thank you for you advice.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not very well optimized. As it is, it will always call either the show or hide Scrollbar methods. You should probably modify it such as it hides it only if visible and it displays it only if hidden.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually my code is quite optimized, I have put the example above just for the sake of clarity and I hide the scrollbar only if visible :)

Comment: we should assume that such checking - if any - is done in the hide/show methods (though I wouldn't expect it  beeing really necessary: the components typically guard themselves against unneeded resetting with the same value, didn't look in that case, though :) The general rule (okay: mine) is to put as little logic into a listener as we can get along with, simply pass-on the course direction to some method that knows all the dirty details, don't smear them across places.

Comment: @kleopatra `JComponent#setVisible` indeed does this. I just checked it in the source and was starting on my comment, but you beat me to it

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. There was certain performance issue in my app that caused such delays.
Thank you for your effort and piece of information and advice you provided.